# Docker iptables seems to limit upload speed in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: iptables, docker

I faced the following issue:

Docker itself create some iptables default rules.
Once they are applied, my upload speed get slowed down to 500 mbit.
Once I reinstall iptables to clear the rules, it get back to normal speed.

Speedtest before:

> Download: 936.95 Mbps (data used: 422.0 MB) Upload: 821.44 Mbps (data used: 370.9 MB)

Speedtest after:

> Download: 937.17 Mbps (data used: 423.2 MB) Upload: 489.61 Mbps (data used: 244.9 MB)

Comment: Not quite sure what you’re asking. Could you [edit] your question to include which version of Ubuntu the host is running, how you conducted your speed test (where did you upload to?), and what the current problem is? I’ve been using Docker on Ubuntu for years and have not observed any network degradation, so being able to duplicate the problem will be key to offering any solutions (though it seems you’ve solved your problem) 

Comment: show us the iptables rule set that docker created.

Comment: That was my solution:
https://docs.hetzner.com/robot/dedicated-server/troubleshooting/performance-intel-i218-nic/ Seems a bug with e1000